Is there a way to add running to grouped dataframe?
I want have variable row in such a way that for soo1 the row is just 1, for soo1 the row is 2.... Any thoughts?
library(dplyr)

data1 <- tibble(
  "id" = c("soo1", "soo1", "soo2", "soo2", "soo3"),
  "amount" = c(100, 21, 23, 23, 45)
) |> 
  group_by(id) |> 
  mutate(row = row_number())


You could use cur_group_id to add an identifier for the group:
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)

tibble(
  "id" = c("soo1", "soo1", "soo2", "soo2", "soo3"),
  "amount" = c(100, 21, 23, 23, 45)
) |> 
  group_by(id) |> 
  mutate(row = cur_group_id())
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>   id    amount   row
#>   <chr>  <dbl> <int>
#> 1 soo1     100     1
#> 2 soo1      21     1
#> 3 soo2      23     2
#> 4 soo2      23     2
#> 5 soo3      45     3

